# Titanium setup runtime error

Tags: android, ios, titanium, development-environment

I’m trying to set up Titanium Studio, but I get error number **1073741511**  in the downloading step.

Can you tell me how to solve this or what exactly the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by manually download and install the JDK and
add this variables below to the `system environment variables` :

```
android_sdk – The path to the Android SDK, similar (if not the same) to C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows
JAVA_HOME – The path to the JDK, similar (if not the same) to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_22
```

[image]